# Why does the records in the db get deleted automatic?

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have no Idea why records from a specific db table are getting automatic deleted. I have no PHP/code that delete the records

The table looks like this. 
http://i64.tinypic.com/2r5vpe8.png

What should i look for to solve this?

Comment: Do not link to external resources, include code (not pictures) in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Check that you did not update empty values into a column.. Or make sure you did not use "truncate table blah" in your scripts